# HTMLUnit page not containing 'src' tag

Tags: java, htmlunit

I'm trying to get the link to the `.mp4` of this page `https://www.clippituser.tv/c/xqbnrq`

In Chrome devtools I can see it fine:

```
<video playsinline="playsinline" webkit-playsinline="" class="vjs-tech" id="vjs_video_3_html5_api" tabindex="-1" preload="auto" autoplay="" src="https://clips.clippit.tv/xqbnrq/360.mp4"></video>
```

My code is:

```
Page page = null;
try {
  webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(5000);
  page = webClient.getPage(url);
} catch (IOException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}

DomNodeList<DomElement> source = ((HtmlPage) page).getElementsByTagName("video");
String videoUrl = source.get(0).getAttribute("src");
```

`source.get(0).asXml()` is the same apart from missing `src` where the `.mp4` is:

```
<video playsinline="playsinline" webkit-playsinline="" class="vjs-tech" id="vjs_video_3_html5_api" tabindex="-1" preload="auto" autoplay="autoplay"/>
```

This code works fine for getting videos from other websites so not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: I also have this issue it's not fixed.

Answer (score 3):

At first - webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(5000); is not an option. You have to call this AFTER retrieving the page.

As of HtmlUnit 2.61.0 there is a bug in the XMLHttpRequest handling, that leads to an ArrayIndexOutOfBounds exception. This is now fixed and a new Snapshot version will be available soon.

But after the fix the page still reports

```
VIDEOJS: "ERROR:" "(CODE:4 MEDIA_ERR_SRC_NOT_SUPPORTED)"
No compatible source was found for this media.
{"code":4,"message":"No compatible source was found for this media."
```

Looks like there is some js code that checks the 'browser' to figure out if the video is playable before adding the source. But the js code for the page is complex, it is not that easy to figure out which check fails.

If you like to get this also fixed, please open an issue for HtmlUnit at github and try to isolate the problem (https://htmlunit.sourceforge.io/submittingJSBugs.html).

Comment: I also have this issue it's not fixed, please fix it bro. You can't scrape videos with this issue.